# How to remove the last index in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

```js
let array=[
  [
    "Test1",
    "4",
    "160496"
  ],
  [
    "Test2",
    "6",
    "38355"
  ],
  [
    "Test3",
    "1",
    "1221781"
  ],
  [
    "Test4",
    "3",
    "124315"
  ],
  [
    "Test5",
    "5",
    "29509"
  ],
  [
    "Test6",
    "7",
    "47742"
  ],
  [
    "Test7",
    "2",
    "231034"
  ]
]
```

I need only the first two indexes from an array of array
Ex:

```js
[["Test1","4"],["Test2","6"],["Test3","1"],["Test4","3"],["Test5","5"],["Test6","7"],["Test7","2"]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You'll probably want to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on each element

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon: Slice and splice

Comment: array.slice(0,2). Use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let array=[
  [
    "Test1",
    "4",
    "160496"
  ],
  [
    "Test2",
    "6",
    "38355"
  ],
  [
    "Test3",
    "1",
    "1221781"
  ],
  [
    "Test4",
    "3",
    "124315"
  ],
  [
    "Test5",
    "5",
    "29509"
  ],
  [
    "Test6",
    "7",
    "47742"
  ],
  [
    "Test7",
    "2",
    "231034"
  ]
];

array.forEach(x=>
  (x.splice((x.length-1), 1))?x:false
);
 console.log(array);
```

Comment: `array.map` anyways create a new array, then why are we disturbing the original array? also why this answer was downvoted without any comment? any reason for that?

Comment: @Nitheesh You probably answered your last two questions with your first one.

Comment: @VLAZ sorry? could not catch that

Comment: @Nitheesh your last two questions were "*why this answer was downvoted without any comment? any reason for that?*" and I think the answer is your first question: "*array.map anyways create a new array, then why are we disturbing the original array?*"

Answer (score 0):

Tray using `array.map` to generate new array from an existing one

```js
const array = [
  ["Test1", "4", "160496"],
  ["Test2", "6", "38355"],
  ["Test3", "1", "1221781"],
  ["Test4", "3", "124315"],
  ["Test5", "5", "29509"],
  ["Test6", "7", "47742"],
  ["Test7", "2", "231034"]
];
const newArray = array.map(item => [item[0], item[1]]);
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you don't want to alter the original `array` variable and you want to remove only the last index, no matter how long the inner array is, the below solution may help.

```js
let array=[
  [
    "Test1",
    "4",
    "160496"
  ],
  [
    "Test2",
    "6",
    "38355"
  ],
  [
    "Test3",
    "1",
    "1221781"
  ],
  [
    "Test4",
    "3",
    "124315"
  ],
  [
    "Test5",
    "5",
    "29509"
  ],
  [
    "Test6",
    "7",
    "47742"
  ],
  [
    "Test7",
    "2",
    "231034"
  ]
]

const newArray = array.map(innerArray => innerArray.slice(0, -1));

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This wil iterate through your array and remove the last element of each nested array

```
for (let nestedArray of array) {
    let lastIndex = nestedArray.length - 1
    nestedArray.splice(lastIndex, 1)
}
```

Read about splice here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice